# Facebook "Add to my page" button

Tags: facebook, xfbml

I have looked all over the internet.  Can anyone point me to some resources for adding the "Add to my page" button on my facebook pages tab app.  I have seen other pages do it, so i know its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an app to a page via:

1. The API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs
2. The 'Add to my page' link on the app's profile page (deprecated, see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/ for details)
3. The new 'Add Page Tab' dialog you can use in your app (see the above blog post again for more details, there's full docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/ , and  a short example below):

Create a link on your site to:

```
 https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=URL_TO_REDIRECT_USER_TO_AFTER_ADDING
```

You can also trigger this using the Facebook Javascript SDK (details on the doc above)

Comment: Is there a way to redirect them back to their Facebook page?

Comment: Does putting the page URL in the 'next' parameter not work? (for option 3 there) - for option 1 you can do whatever you want because they're on your app already

Answer (score 1):

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id="yourAPPID"&next="your_app_url","PageTab","width=1000,height=300"

This is what you need to execute on your browser and it will solve your problem

Or you can add your app via this simple form I made, which uses the above code so you don't have to look any more, since facebook is removing the "add to my page" along with the app profile page

https://admine.eu/addapp.html

Comment: Your answer must contain enough information to answer the question. Answers which contain no useful information except an off-site link are doomed to be deleted.

Comment: Apart from the terrible grammer and use of chat-speak "u", yes.

Comment: my dear friend i'm not here to learn perfect English... i just try to be helpful to others... as long as U can understand me i'm ok with it :)

Comment: We're not ok with it. You're expected to communicate professionally here, and chat-speak is specifically disallowed. Please learn to type "you" instead of "u". One is acceptable here, the other is not.

Comment: you is 3 bytes(ascii) or 6 bytes(unicode)  on the other hand u is 1 byte or 2 bytes so ...both are understandable but u is more efficient for the internet and if you multiply the amount of text in forums you will probably realize that chat-speak is actually a good thing...

Comment: Irrelevant, stop debating this. I'm *telling* you the rules, if you want to debate it go to meta.stackoverflow.com where this has been covered many times. You are wrong, and chat-speak is not acceptable here.